# website not showing properly on other devices

Tags: vpn, ftp, wordpress

I've just finished editing my website on my localhost (starting from wordpress.org) and after I uploaded it to the live web host using ftp, the live website now looks exactly like the local version.

but when I try it on my mobile phone the website only shows an empty page, and when I try it on any other devices the website looks broken as if there is no CSS applied.

the website looks fine even if I use VPN and/or incognito mode to access it from my computer.

I tried following the 7 steps from [How to Move WordPress From Local Server to Live Site](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/) but it still doesn't make any difference..

does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

the website is http://bose-bali.com

Comment: Logs from the server would be a good start. Are the permissions of the uploaded files world readable? If you don't have logs, at least a listing of the files would be good to include in your question, with a mention of which ones work and which ones don't. You can [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: Not sure if you fixed it, but it looks fine for me on cell and desktop.

Comment: yes i did try editing the Authentication Unique Keys and Salts in wp-config.php. I guess that was what fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at the site here's a few things I can see:

- The site is responsive (check by resizing browser window)
- displays nicely on my desktop, phone & tablet over wifi or data using chrome no problem (devices are using oreo and nougat respectively)

Couple other issues you'll want to look after pretty quickly:

- in mobile view the hamburger menu is blank (check that you have it set to display the menu you created on click)
- in your menu the "home" link goes to a non existent page (404 error) /bose1 - it should link to the URL of the site

Best of luck!